# Sqoop import - incremental load using append

Tags: sqoop

I have tried incremental load using append option in sqoop import. It is appended in the HDFS file where as when I query the table the values are NULL.

Command :

`sqoop import --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" --username=retail_dba --password=cloudera --table departments --append --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/departments --where "department_id>7" --outdir java_files`

Hive Result :

```
hive> select * from departments;
OK
2   Fitness
3   Footwear
4   Apparel
5   Golf
6   Outdoors
7   Fan Shop 
NULL    NULL
```

Comment: what is the field delimiter in `departments` table?

Comment: please share your data in `/user/hive/warehouse/departments `

Comment: While creating table I gave FIELD TERMINATED BY '\t' and the data available in /user/hive/warehouse/departments is 2,Fitness
3,Footwear
4,Apparel
5,Golf
6,Outdoors
7,Fan Shop
8000,Testing

Comment: your data is comma separated and  FIELD TERMINATED BY '\t. Then you should see all NULL

Comment: may be data is not properly formatted in comment. Edit your question and add data there.

Comment: I tried changing the delimitor to ',' in hive table. It worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That changing delimiter did not work for me, I made sure the Hive delimiter option for sqoop creation was set as I expected, and it worked. Interesting.